# A problem about lcm and irrational number

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Denote by $A_n$ the least common multiple of the integers from 1 to n, prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{f(n)}{A_n}$ is irrational, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. This problem was introduced by Erdős and published on Pi Mu Epsilon Journal Problems without a solution!

I have difficulty finishing it.

Comment: Okay, … so what’s your question now?

Comment: A proof strategy similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational should work. But instead of taking the sum upto just b, you take it upto some multiple of b chosen appropriately to cancel the power of f

Comment: @Sandeep Silwal: I am finding it not that easy... the proof strategy for $e$ basically uses that you have a rational approximation $R$ of $e$ with denominator $D$ (by taking the partial sums), and you show that the remainder is smaller than $1/D$. Here, it is quite easy to show that $A_n\sum_{k > n}{\frac{1}{A_k}}$ is unbounded.

Comment: Let $b_k$ a sequence of integers $\ge 2$ such that every prime divides infinitely many $b_k$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{\prod_{m \le k} b_m} \in \Bbb{Q}, a_k \in 0 \ldots b_k-1 \iff ( \forall k \ge K, a_k = 0) \lor (\forall k \ge K, a_k = b_k-1)$ @Mindlack

Comment: @reuns: I’m agreeing so far. But how do you define your $b_k$ and $a_k$ such that the constraints are met, since $A_{n+1}=A_n$ for infinitely many $n$?